# How to post and get data from Firebase in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I just recently started learning firebase and  i need assistance in connecting firebase with my ruby project.How can i save user data to firebase and get the data again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am going to make a few assumptions here:

You have completed Configuring Firebase (see firebase docs):

1.) Created a Firebase Project

2.) Did Firebase Project Settings

3.) Got Firebase Database Credential

Now, we can move on to fun stuff --> Rails:

1.) Install the 3rd party firebase library `gem install firebase`  make sure you crawl the documentation at https://github.com/oscardelben/firebase-ruby

2.) Make a module to hold all your firebase logic
Right now there are there are only simple crud operations supported by the gem
set(path, data, query_options)

- get(path, query_options)
- push(path, data, query_options)
- delete(path, query_options)
- update(path, data, query_options)

Example:

```
class ExampleClass

attr_reader :firebase

def initialize
  @firebase = Firebase::Client.new(ENV[‘FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL’], 
  ENV[‘FIREBASE_DATABASE_SECRET’])
end

def get(path)
 @firebase.get(path)
 end

def set(path, data)
 @firebase.set(path, data)
 end

def delete(path)
 @firebase.delete(path)
 end

def push(path, data)
 @firebase.push(path, data)
 end

def update(path, data)
 @firebase.update(path, data)
 end

end
```

That should get you started/going, go through the docs for this gem as it is relatively lightweight and straightforward and the firebase documentation is really good.

Cheers